# any efficient way to count binary values in columns of big data table?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, bigdata

I am using big-query for Chicago crime data in google cloud platform. However, I want to count number of arrest and non arrest per crime type. It is easy to count this in pandas but it's not intuitive for me how to count binary values in dataframe with big query. Can anyone give me possible idea to make this count?

**data**

because Chicago crime data is big I am not able to give reproducible example here, but it is very easy to preview crime data from here: [Chicago crime data](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2001-to-present/ijzp-q8t2)

here is little preview:

[image: crime data preview]

**my big query**:

```
SELECT
  primary_type,
  count(arrest),
  COUNTIF(year = 2015) AS arrests_2015,
  COUNTIF(year = 2016) AS arrests_2016
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime`
WHERE
  arrest = TRUE
  AND year IN (2001,
    2018)
  AND primary_type NOT IN ('OTHER OFFENSE', ' all non-criminal types')
GROUP BY
  primary_type,
  arrest
```

but this query gives me empty output, I don't know how to make it work.

**goal**:

from Chicago crime data table, I want to extract number of total arrest and non-arrest for each primary type, I want to exclude OTHER OFFENSE and all non-criminal types until end of 2018.

how can I correct my big-query to get my expected output? any efficient big-query script to get expected query output? any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below should work

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  primary_type,
  COUNT(arrest) arrest_total,
  COUNTIF(year = 2015) AS arrests_2015,
  COUNTIF(year = 2016) AS arrests_2016
FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime`
WHERE arrest = TRUE
AND year BETWEEN 2001 AND 2018
AND primary_type NOT IN ('OTHER OFFENSE', ' all non-criminal types')
GROUP BY primary_type, arrest
```

I think  your issue was in below line, where you selected ONLY 2001 and 2018 instead of all years in between (to at least include 2015, and 2016)

```
AND year IN (2001, 2018)
```

So, instead you should use below one

```
AND year BETWEEN 2001 AND 2018
```

Also, if you want to include non-arrests, you can use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  primary_type,
  arrest,
  COUNT(arrest) arrest_total,
  COUNTIF(year = 2015) AS arrests_2015,
  COUNTIF(year = 2016) AS arrests_2016
FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime`
WHERE year BETWEEN 2001 AND 2018
AND primary_type NOT IN ('OTHER OFFENSE', ' all non-criminal types')
GROUP BY primary_type, arrest
```

Note: I removed `WHERE arrest = TRUE` here and added `arrest` to SELECT list

Rather than these few adjustments - your initial query was quite correct

If you want to have one output row per `primary_type` you can use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  primary_type,
  COUNTIF(arrest) arrests,
  COUNTIF(NOT arrest) non_arrests,
  COUNT(arrest) arrest_total,
  COUNTIF(year = 2015) AS arrests_2015,
  COUNTIF(year = 2016) AS arrests_2016
FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime`
WHERE year BETWEEN 2001 AND 2018
AND primary_type NOT IN ('OTHER OFFENSE', ' all non-criminal types')
GROUP BY primary_type
```

Moreover - if you can "expand" year counts like below (for 2015 for example)

```
COUNTIF(year = 2015 AND arrest) AS arrests_2015,
COUNTIF(year = 2015 AND NOT arrest) AS non_arrests_2015,
```

> Is there any programmatic way to count number of arrest from 2001 to 2018 per crime type

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  primary_type,
  year,
  COUNTIF(arrest) arrests,
  COUNTIF(NOT arrest) non_arrests,
  COUNT(arrest) arrest_total
FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime`
WHERE year BETWEEN 2001 AND 2018
AND primary_type NOT IN ('OTHER OFFENSE', ' all non-criminal types')
GROUP BY primary_type, year
```

Comment: I look up bigquery documentation, I could count binary value such as : `COUNTIF(arrest=True) as num_arrest, COUNTIF(arrest=False) as num_non_arrest`. How can I change fourth and fifth line in more compact way? Thanks

Comment: Absolutely true. More over - because arrest is BOOLEAN you can just use COUNTIF(arrest) and COUNTIF(NOT arrest) - i will add to my answer in a moment

Comment: I want to return number of arrest and non arrest for each year for per crime type, could you point me out how to retrieve this even more efficient way? Thank you

Comment: see update, I've answered your initial question. if you have more questions please post new one and we will be more than happy to answer them :o)

Comment: thanks. Is there any programmatic way to count number of arrest from 2001 to 2018 per crime type, I mean instead of doing `COUNTIF(year = 2015) AS arrests_2015`, can I iterate `year`? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure, you can add `year` in GROUP BY and SELECT statement and remove year specific counts.

Comment: how? could you add that in your answer?

Comment: why I have error when I do like this: `ORDER BY primary_type, arrest DESC` ?

Comment: I think you meant `ORDER BY primary_type, arrests DESC` - As I mentioned  - if you have any more questions  - please post new question. this is the way SO works.